# WriteAllBytes Error

Tags: c#, wpf

I am using the below code in `C#` in a `WPF` Application

I am using this method to save one file to disk:

```
    private void executeSaveAttachment(object parameter)
    {
        SaveFileDialog dlg = new SaveFileDialog();
        {
            dlg.AddExtension = true;
            dlg.DefaultExt = "xlsx";
            dlg.Filter = "New Excel(*.xlsx)|*.*";
            foreach (var table in Table)
            {
                if (dlg.ShowDialog() ?? false)
                {

                    File.WriteAllBytes(dlg.FileName, table.Data);

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I am trying to use this method to store multiple files to a location the user is able to choose but give it default filename from the `Title` Property and add `.xlsx` extension.  The `class` is named `Table` and the `Data` Property is the binary.

Here is the method that is giving 
Error   4   No overload for method 'WriteAllBytes' takes 1 arguments

```
private void executeSaveAttachments(object parameter)
        {

            {
                System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog flg = new System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog();


                foreach (var table in Table)
                {
                    if (flg.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
                    {

                        File.WriteAllBytes(Path.Combine(flg.SelectedPath,  table.Title + ".dat"));

                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the error suggests, [WriteAllBytes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.writeallbytes.aspx) doesn't have an overload with one argument. You must specify the bytes to write, as well as the path. You have it right in your first block so simply do the same again:

```
File.WriteAllBytes(Path.Combine(flg.SelectedPath,  table.Title + ".dat"), table.Data);
```

Answer (score 2):

You are missing an argument and you aren't passing data to write to your location. `Path.Combine(flg.SelectedPath,  table.Title + ".dat")` is one argument, you forgot to pass the second argument.

```
File.WriteAllBytes(
    Path.Combine(flg.SelectedPath,  table.Title + ".dat"),
    table.Data
);
```